# printer configuration failures and upgrade failures

Tags: upgrade, printing

This has become more and more of a problem. I was using 4.8 Kubuntu and could not configure remote printers under system setting printer configuration.

I updated to 4.134. I then downloaded print manager since that was supposed to be the new way to configure printers. I could not find any way to actually run print manager so I tried overwriting my /bin files in root. (Don't ever do that). I repaired my damaged /bin directory with

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media
cd /media
cd /bin
sudo rm sh
sudo ln -s bash sh 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash
```

After that, I did not have a desktop, Which I got back through the following:

```
cat ~/.kde/env/desktop_effects
export KWIN_DIRECT_GL=1
echo $KWIN_COMPOSE
KWIN_DIRECT_GL=1 KWIN_COMPOSE=O2 kwin --replace &
```

After that, I got a notice to upgrade to 4.14 which now does not work because of a failure to purge PPAs. I am still in 4.13.

Then, still getting printer config on my system settings, I deleted `printer-config` in Synaptic and reinstalled print manager. 
Still do not have the ability to configure printers and cannot find and run print manager.
Printers yields a configuration file error and cannot run printers in system settings. The config printer icon is no longer showing. Reinstalled printer configuration which still does not have config printer icon and printers gives same print configuration file error.

I should be able to nuke and reinstall everything somehow and after the dust settles, be able to configure a printer. CUPS cannot find remote printers either.

Do you have any suggestions? And I promise not to ever, ever, ever overwrite my /bin again.